# AngularJS How to shuffle data again in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm making a simple web page, 
It just shows one random quotation when page loaded.

I brought json data and used filter below

```
app.filter('shuffle', function() {
var shuffledArr = [],
shuffledLength = 0;
return function(arr) {
    var o = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
    if (shuffledLength == arr.length) return shuffledArr;
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        shuffledArr = o;
    shuffledLength = o.length;
    return o;
};
```

and I using this filter like

```
<section id="bg" ng-controller="QuoteCtrl">
  <div class="wrap_quote" ng-repeat="quote in quotes | shuffle | limitTo:1">
    <pre class="quote">{{ quote.gsx$said.$t }}</pre>
    <p class="from">{{ quote.gsx$from.$t }}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

The question is, how can I load new random data without refresh the page?
I tried this.

```
$scope.loadData = function() {
http.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1e3oNuL79PBq-xSvpovbppM5j4aUzgzHfkl5c6x1HzAc/od6/public/values?alt=json")
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.quotes = response.feed.entry;
  });
}

$scope.loadData();
```

and in html

```
<button ng-click="loadData()">RELOAD</button>
```

but nothing happened...
please help me!

http://plnkr.co/edit/RYcGMf?p=preview

Comment: mark my answer as correct if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loadData()` button is outside your controller. You need to put it inside the controller like this:

```
<section id="bg" ng-controller="QuoteCtrl">
    <div class="wrap_quote" ng-repeat="quote in quotes | shuffle | limitTo:1">
      <span>“</span>
      <pre class="quote">{{ quote.gsx$said.$t }}</pre>
      <p class="from">{{ quote.gsx$from.$t }}<u>{{ quote.gsx$as.$t }}</u></p>
    </div>
  <button ng-click="loadData()">RELOAD</button>
  </section>
```

**EDIT**: Based on the feedback, I took a second look at your code and I think I understand better what you are trying to do. You don't even need to call the page reload over and over. You simply need to load your data once, and call your shuffle filter every time you want to shuffle. Here's how to do that. Add a method to call the filter inside your controller like this:

```
$scope.shuffleData = function(){
  $scope.quotes = $filter('shuffle')($scope.quotes);
};
```

Then change your button to call this method instead of the `loadData()` method:

```
<button ng-click="shuffleData()">RELOAD</button>
```

And get rid of the `shuffledLength = o.length;` in your filter function. Hope this helps.

See it in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G2ULuIsisoMDqw2lVYdX?p=preview) updated from your version.

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the data won't make the shuffle again, because the data will not render the div again. You need to shuffle not inline of the `HTML`.

Here's an way to do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/VBR0IXYMEYOMU9avOW52?p=preview

```js
var shuffle = function(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

$scope.loadData = function() {
  http.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1e3oNuL79PBq-xSvpovbppM5j4aUzgzHfkl5c6x1HzAc/od6/public/values?alt=json")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.quotes = shuffle(response.feed.entry);
    });
}
```

```html
<section id="bg" ng-controller="QuoteCtrl">
  <div class="wrap_quote" ng-repeat="quote in quotes  | limitTo:1">
    <pre class="quote">{{ quote.gsx$said.$t }}</pre>
    <p class="from">{{ quote.gsx$from.$t }}</p>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="loadData()">RELOAD</button>
</section>
```

Comment: + I added a little ☞ ng-repeat="quote in quotes | limitTo:1 "